# Retain data types after concatenating pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, types

The data type for the last column for all the dataframes is "object".
The remaining columns of the `mut` dataframe is binary, whereas the remaining columns of the other dataframes are float.

In my code below, the resulting dataframe `df_scaled` has "object" data type for all the columns.

```
X = df.iloc[:,:-1].astype(int)
X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(mms.fit_transform(X.values), columns=X.columns, index=X.index)
y = df.iloc[:,-1:]

y = df.iloc[:,-1:]
df_scaled = pd.concat([X_scaled,y], axis=1)
df_scaled = pd.concat([mut, df_scaled])
```

Data:

`df`

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': {'hsa-let-7a-3p': 2.082843013790784,
  'hsa-let-7b-5p': 3.5720402468662744,
  'hsa-let-7b-3p': 1.454168803064294,
  'hsa-let-7c-5p': 3.521051767831394},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-01A': {'hsa-let-7a-3p': 2.124989064575205,
  'hsa-let-7b-5p': 3.33033877243824,
  'hsa-let-7b-3p': 1.795842048944672,
  'hsa-let-7c-5p': 3.0978660073056066},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': {'hsa-let-7a-3p': 1.9381691147779496,
  'hsa-let-7b-5p': 3.6787575193202096,
  'hsa-let-7b-3p': 1.4976013154110766,
  'hsa-let-7c-5p': 3.6586682721571377},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': {'hsa-let-7a-3p': 2.0583218372956287,
  'hsa-let-7b-5p': 3.516734922406729,
  'hsa-let-7b-3p': 1.3254164702581286,
  'hsa-let-7c-5p': 3.3594612940444466},
 'category': {'hsa-let-7a-3p': 'miRNA',
  'hsa-let-7b-5p': 'miRNA',
  'hsa-let-7b-3p': 'miRNA',
  'hsa-let-7c-5p': 'miRNA'}})
```

`mut`

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': {'IGF2R': 0, 'NBEA': 0, 'KMT2D': 0, 'HERC2': 0},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-01A': {'IGF2R': 0, 'NBEA': 0, 'KMT2D': 0, 'HERC2': 0},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': {'IGF2R': 0, 'NBEA': 0, 'KMT2D': 0, 'HERC2': 0},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': {'IGF2R': 0, 'NBEA': 1, 'KMT2D': 0, 'HERC2': 0},
 'category': {'IGF2R': 'Mutation',
  'NBEA': 'Mutation',
  'KMT2D': 'Mutation',
  'HERC2': 'Mutation'}})
```

Comment: And what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Concatenate the dataframes but keep the data types as-is.

Comment: can you share the final result for df_scaled (and ideally also X_scaled)?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, as `mms` is undefined. Should we assume it is an instance of `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler`? When I do that (with init as `mms = MinMaxScaler()`), then your code runs just fine on the data provided. The resulting `df_scaled.dtypes` gives `float64` for all columns except the last one.